# Imprimir un mensaje a partir de un input

Tags: javascript, formularios, condiciones, entrada

Mi objetivo es hacer un código con javascript en el que al ingresar un numero en un campo me muestre un mensaje con la calificación del alumno.
El código es el siguiente:

```js
function calcular() {

  var 1 = 100;
  var 2 = 90;
  var 3 = 80;
  var 4 = 70;
  var 5 = 60;

  var nota = document.getElementById('nota').value;

  if (nota <
    var 1) {

    document.write("parametro invalido")
  }

  if (nota <
    var 2) {

    document.write("Examen Excelente")
  }

  if (nota <
    var 3) {

    document.write("Examen muy bueno")
  }

  if (nota <
    var 4) {

    document.write("Examen bueno")
  }

  if (nota <
    var 5) {

    document.write("Examen regular")
  }

  if (nota >
    var 5) {

    document.write("Desaprobado")
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>conversor</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" name="nota" id="nota">
  <button onclick="calcular()">calcular</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `document.write` escribe lo que sea que le pongas dentro de la función en el documento quitando cualquier otra cosa que esté en el DOM, texto, inputs, párrafos, etc. Y no puedes nombrar variables como números en JS, el navegador te mandará error al querer ejecutar tu código.

Comment: Las variables en Javascript **No deben empezar con numero**, esto es elemental en los lenguajes de programacion.

Comment: Y ¿por qué empiezas los nombres de variable con números, y no sólo, sino que no usas caracteres alfanuméricos. Otro gallo cantaría si llamases a tus variables algo así: `var miNota1 ... var miNota2 ...` etc. Las nombres de variable deben darte una idea de para qué las creaste, sólo con ver su nombre.

Comment: Tu logica me da cosas, es enserio

Comment: No tienen mucho sentido los ifs, si nota se encuentra entre -infinito y 99 solo va a imprimir parametro invalido, de hecho los 4 primeros else if los va a ignorar siempre.

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido, corregir una publicacion (que inicialmente tenia un problema), y corregirla para indicar otro error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Que ocurre en el código?

**1)** Las variables tanto en Javascript como en la mayoria de los lenguajes de programacion **No deben empezar por un numero**, esto es lo que ha causado el error.

**2)** Debes usar la sentencia `else if`, **para que no se repitan los mensajes cuando la condicion se cumpla multiples veces**, al agregar `else if`, solo se puede cumplir una de las condiciones y por lo tanto obtener el resultado que buscas.

***Teniendo en cuenta esto, podrias hacer algo como esto:***

```js
function calcular() {

  var uno = 100;
  var dos = 90;
  var tres = 80;
  var cuatro = 70;
  var cinco = 60;

  var nota = document.getElementById('nota').value;

  if (nota < uno) {
    document.write("parametro invalido")
  }

  else if (nota < dos) {
    document.write("Examen Excelente")
  }

  else if (nota < tres) {
    document.write("Examen muy bueno")
  }

  else if (nota < cuatro) {
    document.write("Examen bueno")
  }

  else if (nota < cinco) {
    document.write("Examen regular")
  }

  else if (nota > cinco) {
    document.write("Desaprobado")
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>conversor</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="nota" name="nota">
  <button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pregunta: estuve leyendo sobre las condicionales que me dijo es esta pagina:
http://www.elvisualista.com/index.php/2016/03/31/javascript-para-novatos-7o/
pero sea cual sea la nota que ingrese siempre me devuelve parámetro invalido (soy muy nuevo en esto, como ya te habrás dado cuenta) y no logro detectar el error. 
intente hacerlo conforme a lo que leí pero sigue igual

Comment: @condor12 El problema que tienes esta en el algoritmo, tu colocas la condicion que todos los numeros menores a 100, son un parametro invalido, y en adelante verificas con los numeros menores a 100 (90,80,70), siempre va a ejecutarse el primer condicional.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias a todos! por su ayuda finalmente entendí

Answer (score 0):

El unico error es como nombras a tus variables, cambiando los nombres funciona todo bien. Recuerda que los numeros son comparativos, cuando comparas una variable `numero` que su valor es `4` (por ejemplo) con una variable que su nombre sea `1` puede causar un conflicto compilado ya que es interpretado como valor.

```js
function calcular() {

  var uno = 100;
  var dos = 90;
  var tres = 80;
  var cuatro = 70;
  var cinco = 60;

  var nota = document.getElementById('nota').value;

  if (nota < uno) {
    document.write("parametro invalido")
  } else if (nota < dos) {
    document.write("Examen Excelente")
  } else if (nota < tres) {
    document.write("Examen muy bueno")
  } else if (nota < cuatro) {
    document.write("Examen bueno")
  } else if (nota < cinco) {
    document.write("Examen regular")
  } else if (nota > cinco) {
    document.write("Desaprobado")
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>conversor</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" name="nota" id="nota">
  <button onclick="calcular()">calcular</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sigo esperando la aclaración a la persona que voto negativo....

Comment: no fui quien votó negativo. pero no debería ser `elseif` ? la lógica de su respuesta parece ser errónea. espero se corrija. Saludos.

Comment: @DarkFenix Si, la mejore!, pero el error no se causaba porque fuera `elseif` sino, por la declaración de variables. Por eso pregunte por el voto negativo